# Verifying paypal incoming webhook - Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin, paypal

I am trying to verify a paypal webhook using the headers. I have this code which gets the headers

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("paypal")
    fun paypalMapping(
            @RequestHeader("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG") transmissionSig:String,
            @RequestHeader("PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO") authAlgo:String,
            @RequestHeader("PAYPAL-CERT-URL") certUrl:String,
            @RequestBody paypalOrder: PaypalOrder
    ){
        println("Incoming paypal order!")
        println(transmissionSig)
        println(authAlgo)
        println(certUrl)
    }
```

However I am unsure what I should be comparing these strings to. The only sdk i am using is the checkout one, as the general REST one is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple methods, DIY Verification or the Webhook API, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#verify-event-notifications

Don't use the REST SDKs as they are no longer maintained.

Comment: When I go to the events API on the dashboard the URL contains /v1, wouldnt that imply its deprecated as well?

Comment: No, there are no v2 webhook APIs

Comment: So what should I do

Comment: Well as mentioned in the answer, either the DIY verification or a direct integration with the Webhook APIs for verification

Comment: Well thats what im confused about, the DIY verification, so do I have to send a webhook to paypals servers or something?

Comment: No, that would be the API method.  Read the DIY verification guide if you want to consider its calculations.

Comment: Well yea thats what I dont really understand, Ive worked out how to get the headers I just dont know what to do with them